# Am I using the term "limiting value" correctly?

Tags: limits

Suppose "the limit as x goes to a of f(x) is L".  I believe in school I had teachers used the term "limiting value" to refer to a.  Is this the correct terminally to refer to a?

I would like to use this in my class, but I want to make sure I'm using the correct terminology.  I want to tell my class that when working with limits "It doesn't matter how the function is defined at the limiting value, or even whether its defined at all there...".

Comment: In my language, there is no expression for what you want, and we get by just fine. We phrase the sentence as "It does not matter if the function is defined at a given point, it may still have a limit at that point". Everytime I read math literature in english, I also saw this similar terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally "limiting value" refers to the limit that the expression tends to, and not the point to which the limit is taken. Indeed I find it a bit troublesome that we don't seem to have a term (in English) for that point. I would end up phrasing what you want to say almost exactly the way *5xum* did.